# How to copy values from one column in df1 to df2 based on specific values in other three columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with similar shapes and column names and would like to copy the values of df1['property'] and paste them in df2['property'], but there is a condition.

df1:

```
i   j   k   property
1   1   1   10
1   1   2   20
1   1   3   30
1   2   1   40
1   2   2   50
1   2   3   60
1   3   1   70
1   3   2   80
1   3   3   90
2   1   1   100
2   1   2   110
2   1   3   120
2   2   1   130
2   2   2   140
2   2   3   150
2   3   1   160
2   3   2   170
2   3   3   180
3   1   1   190
3   1   2   200
3   1   3   210
3   2   1   220
3   2   2   230
3   2   3   240
3   3   1   250
3   3   2   260
3   3   3   270
```

df2:

```
i   j   k   property
1   1   1   100
2   1   1   100
3   1   1   100
1   2   1   100
2   2   1   100
3   2   1   100
1   3   1   100
2   3   1   100
3   3   1   100
1   1   2   100
2   1   2   100
3   1   2   100
1   2   2   100
2   2   2   100
3   2   2   100
1   3   2   100
2   3   2   100
3   3   2   100
1   1   3   100
2   1   3   100
3   1   3   100
1   2   3   100
2   2   3   100
3   2   3   100
1   3   3   100
2   3   3   100
3   3   3   100
```

The other three columns (i, j, k) represent different positions and the copied value of df1['property'] must replace df2['property'] only where df1[['i','j','k']] is the same as df2[['i','j','k']]. Anyone could help me with this?

In my mind, I should use map function but I do not know how to do this for three columns condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want [`DatFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df2['property']=( df2.drop('property',axis=1)
                     .merge(df1,on=['i','j','k'],how = 'left')['property']
                     .fillna(df2['property']) )
print(df2)

#or this:

#df2['property']=( df2.merge(df1,on=['i','j','k'],how = 'left')['property_y'] 
#                     .fillna(df2['property']) )
```

---

We could also use [`DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df2_update=df2.set_index(['i','j','k'])
df2_update.update(df1.set_index(['i','j','k']))
df2_update = df2_update.reset_index()
print(df2_update)
```

**Output**

```
    i  j  k  property
0   1  1  1        10
1   2  1  1       100
2   3  1  1       190
3   1  2  1        40
4   2  2  1       130
5   3  2  1       220
6   1  3  1        70
7   2  3  1       160
8   3  3  1       250
9   1  1  2        20
10  2  1  2       110
11  3  1  2       200
12  1  2  2        50
13  2  2  2       140
14  3  2  2       230
15  1  3  2        80
16  2  3  2       170
17  3  3  2       260
18  1  1  3        30
19  2  1  3       120
20  3  1  3       210
21  1  2  3        60
22  2  2  3       150
23  3  2  3       240
24  1  3  3        90
25  2  3  3       180
26  3  3  3       270
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(i=np.repeat([1,2,3],9), j=np.repeat([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],3), k=[1,2,3]*9,\
        property=range(10,280,10)))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(k=np.repeat([1,2,3],9), j=np.repeat([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],3), i=[1,2,3]*9,\
        property=100))


df = pd.concat([df1,df2.rename(columns={"i":"ii","j":"jj","k":"kk","property":"property2"})],axis=1)

df.property2 = np.where((df.i==df.ii)&(df.j==df.jj)&(df.k==df.kk),df.property,df.property2)
df=df[["ii","jj","kk","property2"]]
print(df)
```

Gives:

```
    ii  jj  kk  property2
0    1   1   1         10
1    2   1   1        100
2    3   1   1        100
3    1   2   1         40
4    2   2   1        100
5    3   2   1        100
6    1   3   1         70
7    2   3   1        100
8    3   3   1        100
9    1   1   2        100
10   2   1   2        110
11   3   1   2        100
12   1   2   2        100
13   2   2   2        140
14   3   2   2        100
15   1   3   2        100
16   2   3   2        170
17   3   3   2        100
18   1   1   3        100
19   2   1   3        100
20   3   1   3        210
21   1   2   3        100
22   2   2   3        100
23   3   2   3        240
24   1   3   3        100
25   2   3   3        100
26   3   3   3        270
```

Comment: Sorry, it isn't the output I wanted. The dataframes have the same columnames but the positions of the values in i, j, k are different. Although @ansev already helped me with a nice answer. Thanks for your help